# How to spawn services before start of debug/run in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have requirement to start Redis server before start of run/debug Django app and possibly to stop the process when debugging is stoppped. I looked at documentation and used `preLaunchTask` to start redis service, however VS Code waits for Redis to terminate before it can start Django server. I want Redis to run in background and VS Code to start Django app parallely. Here are my launch.json and tasks.json.

launch.json (operating system macOS)

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Django",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "start-redis",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/manage.py",
            "args": [
                "runserver",
                "--noreload"
            ],
            "console": "internalConsole",
            "django": true,
        }
    ]
}
```

tasks.json

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [{
        "label": "start-redis",
        "command": "/usr/local/bin/redis-server",
        "type": "process",
        "isBackground": false
    }]
}
```

When I start debugging with above configuration, VS Code starts Redis server in terminal but expects this task to "complete" before it can start Django. I tried setting `"isBackground" : true` now VS Code throws an error `The specified task cannot be tracked` and the Django server doesn't start. I tried setting `presentation` variables in tasks.json and start redis in its own terminal, that too didn't work. I tried starting redis task as shell command `/usr/local/bin/redis-server &` that too didn't work, the process is getting terminated immediately.

Comment: Did you ever find a fix for this? There are multiple bugs logged against VSCode but not solutions. I have a similar issue with running a debugger for an embedded system. My work around is to just manually run the prerequisite task before starting the debugger.

Comment: +1 been struggling with similar for a few day, same result. I can get it to launch, but then it shuts down as soon as the task step ends.